# Is it possible to dynamically run benchmark tests?

Tags: testing, go, benchmarking

I have a few different implementations of an interface, and a variety of factors I want to test them under. End goal being to make a grid of results for different implementations in different situations.

I could write a test for each possible combination, but that gets exhausting:

```
func Benchmark_ImplA_N100_X300(b *testing.B){
   impl := newImplA(100,300)
   runBenchmark(b,impl)
}
```

The more combinations I add, the more I have to copy/paste. This gets cumbersome fast.

I would love to do something like:

```
tests := []testing.InternalBenchmark{}
for _, n := range []int{50,100,500,10000}{
   for _,x := range []int{300,200}{
      for name, gen := range implementations{
         impl = gen(n,x)
         bm := testing.InternalBenchmark{Name: fmt.Sprint(name,x,n)}
         bm.F = func(b *testing.B){
            runBench(b,impl)
         }
         tests = append(tests,bm)
      }
   }
}
testing.RunBenchmarks(anything, tests)
```

so that I can update the list(s) of combinations, and benchmarks will magically run in all combinations. I have tries something like this in main and in TestMain, and nothing ever outputs. I am not sure if I am using it wrong, or if the testing package is just doing something funny.

I really don't care if the `go test` tool can handle it or if there is some other way.

Comment: a simple shell script with go:generate might work as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In your test file (`xxx_test.go`) create your own `TestMain()` function, and inside that after assembling the dynamic benchmark cases (values of struct [`testing.InternalBenchmark`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#InternalBenchmark)), call [`testing.Main()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Main) which properly parses command line flags, creates and sets up [`testing.M`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#M), and prepares and calls [`testing.RunBenchmarks()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#RunBenchmarks). This way your dynamic benchmarks will still be runnable by `go test`.

Notes: `testing.Main()` will never return as it calls [`os.Exit()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit). If you want to perform further logging and calculations on the benchmark results, you may also call [`testing.MainStart()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#MainStart)`.Run()` (which is what `testing.Main()` does), and you may pass the exit code which is returned by [`M.Run()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#M.Run) to `os.Exit()`.

Below comes a complete test file which you can simply run with `go test -bench .`.

The output is: benchmark results of dynamically generated tests (of different implementations with different parameters):

```
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
main.EngineA[impl=0, n=50, x=300]-4       100000             16716 ns/op
main.EngineB[impl=1, n=50, x=300]-4       100000             24788 ns/op
main.EngineA[impl=0, n=50, x=200]-4       100000             10764 ns/op
main.EngineB[impl=1, n=50, x=200]-4       100000             16415 ns/op
main.EngineA[impl=0, n=100, x=300]-4       50000             33426 ns/op
main.EngineB[impl=1, n=100, x=300]-4       30000             48466 ns/op
main.EngineA[impl=0, n=100, x=200]-4       50000             20452 ns/op
main.EngineB[impl=1, n=100, x=200]-4       50000             33134 ns/op
main.EngineA[impl=0, n=500, x=300]-4       10000            163087 ns/op
main.EngineB[impl=1, n=500, x=300]-4        5000            238043 ns/op
main.EngineA[impl=0, n=500, x=200]-4       10000            102662 ns/op
main.EngineB[impl=1, n=500, x=200]-4       10000            163113 ns/op
main.EngineA[impl=0, n=1000, x=300]-4       5000            319744 ns/op
main.EngineB[impl=1, n=1000, x=300]-4       3000            512077 ns/op
main.EngineA[impl=0, n=1000, x=200]-4      10000            201036 ns/op
main.EngineB[impl=1, n=1000, x=200]-4       5000            325714 ns/op
ok      _/xxx/src/play  27.307s
```

And the source (a test file, e.g. `dynbench_test.go`):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type Engine interface {
    Calc()
}

type EngineA struct{ n, x int }

func (e EngineA) Calc() {
    for i := 0; i < e.n; i++ {
        a, b := make([]byte, e.x), make([]byte, e.x)
        copy(b, a)
    }
}

type EngineB struct{ n, x int }

func (e EngineB) Calc() {
    for i := 0; i < e.n*2; i++ {
        a, b := make([]byte, e.x/2), make([]byte, e.x/2)
        copy(b, a)
    }
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    implementations := [](func(n, x int) Engine){
        func(n, x int) Engine { return EngineA{n, x} },
        func(n, x int) Engine { return EngineB{n, x} },
    }

    benchmarks := []testing.InternalBenchmark{}
    for _, n := range []int{50, 100, 500, 1000} {
        for _, x := range []int{300, 200} {
            for name, gen := range implementations {
                impl := gen(n, x)
                bm := testing.InternalBenchmark{
                    Name: fmt.Sprintf("%T[impl=%d, n=%d, x=%d]", impl, name, n, x)}
                bm.F = func(b *testing.B) {
                    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                        impl.Calc()
                    }
                }
                benchmarks = append(benchmarks, bm)
            }
        }
    }
    anything := func(pat, str string) (bool, error) { return true, nil }

    testing.Main(anything, nil, benchmarks, nil)
}
```

**Notes #2:**

`testing.Main()`, `testing.MainStart()` and `testing.InternalBenchmark` may change (or get removed) in a future release of Go:

> An internal function / internal type but exported because it is cross-package; part of or called by the implementation of the "go test" command.

Comment: I would also recommend to use `testing.B.Run("name", ...)` instead of `testing.InternalBenchmark`

Answer (score 3):

I suppose reading the docs would help. I overlooked

[`func Benchmark(f func(b *B)) BenchmarkResult`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark)

which will run my function wothout need for any test harness at all.

> Benchmark benchmarks a single function. Useful for creating custom
>   benchmarks that do not use the "go test" command.

That way I can iterate through my test cases and create a function for each possibility, then run the benchmark directly.